# Does boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml preserve the order?

Tags: c++, xml, parsing, tree, boost-propertytree

Considering the following xml element:

```
<elem>
    <sub_elem name="first">
    <sub_elem name="second">
</elem>
```

Concerning the property tree populated by boost::property_tree::xml_parser::read_xml, is it guaranteed that sub_elem "first" will be before sub_elem "second"?

The [documentation](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/property_tree/xml_parser/read_xml_idp96436280.html) states:

> Reads XML from an input stream and **translates** it to property tree.

However it depends what "translates" means exactly.

Comment: As far as I know the order of the elements is not specified in XML standard, thus you should not rely on it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From property tree documentation: https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/doc/html/property_tree/container.html I deduce that order of elements in XML file is preserved

> It is very important to remember that the property sequence is not
>   ordered by the key. **It preserves the order of insertion**. It closely
>   resembles a std::list. Fast access to children by name is provided via
>   a separate lookup structure. Do not attempt to use algorithms that
>   expect an ordered sequence (like binary_search) on a node's children.

Looking at internal code in https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_51_0/boost/property_tree/detail/xml_parser_read_rapidxml.hpp one may see traversing over nodes and *push_back* calls. It should indeed work in simplest way of preserving order.